# MEF Metadata vs. Value

Tags: c#, metadata, mef

I'm a complete beginner here, so this might be a really obvious question, I just can't quite seem to understand or find an answer. I've read the MSDN [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx) and most of it makes complete sense.

In the example, they define the following interfaces and give example usage like this;

```
public interface IOperation
{
    int Operate(int left, int right);
}

public interface IOperationData
{
    char Symbol { get; }
}

[Export(typeof(IOperation))]
[ExportMetadata("Symbol", '+')]
public class Add : IOperation
{
    public int Operate(int left, int right)
    {
        return left + right;
    }
}
```

I think I must be misunderstanding something here.

- What's the point of `IOperationData` and `ExportMetadata` ?
- Why can't I just drop them both and add `char Symbol {get;}` to `IOperation` ?

Then I could just use `Add.Value.Symbol` instead of `Add.Metadata.Smybol`. I guess that's not really a huge change, but it does mean I don't need `ExportMetadata`. What's the difference between `Value` and `Metadata` and why does the example use them like it does? Is `Metadata` for properties and `Value` for methods? It doesn't seem very well explained to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MEF allows composable parts to provide their *metadata*. Metadata here is a set of statically-known properties, which is typical for part *type*, not for the type *instance*.

Suppose you're building a GUI for calculator in the given example.
Each operation is a plugin here, which being loaded via MEF container. You don't want to instantiate every plugin until user selection, but you want to build the panel with buttons, where each button holds an operation symbol.

That's why you need to use metadata instead of adding `char Symbol {get;}` to `IOperation`:

- you can access metadata without instantiation of part (this could be expensive);
- the metadata belongs to the composable part, and every instance of that part should have the same metadata (although calculator example isn't a good choice for understanding that fact).

You're describing metadata interface `IOperationData` and applying `ExportMetadata` attribute to the composable part definition. Then, at run-time, MEF looks at `Add` class, and dynamically builds `IOperationData` implementation. The instance of that implementation being initialized with values, provided in `ExportMetadata`. And, finally, you can access the values of `IOperationData` implementation with `Add.Metadata.Smybol` later in host application.

**UPDATE**.
`ExportMetadata` allows you to add multiple metadata values, but it is often more convenient to add metadata, using custom attribute, which is inherited from `ExportAttribute`:

```
public interface IMyPlugin {}
public interface IMyMetadata
{
    int Value1 { get; }
    string Value2 { get; }
}

[MetadataAttribute]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class MyExportAttribute : ExportAttribute, IMyMetadata
{
    public MyExportAttribute(int value1, string value2)
        : base(typeof(IMyPlugin))
    {
        Value1 = value1;
        Value2 = value2;
    }

    public int Value1 { get; private set; }
    public string Value2 { get; private set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
   [MyExport(1, "Orange")] 
   public class MyPlugin : IMyPlugin {}
```

Comment: Right, so Metadata is a way to avoid initialisation, but still get info. That makes sense. To add to that, is it possible to have multiple Metadata values? Do I just add another ExportMetadata below the first?

Comment: Yes, you can add another `ExportMetadata`, this is one of the ways to do what you want. Another way is to make your own `ExportAttribute` (I'll add the sample in my answer).